# How to send google analytics revenue by userId?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

**Original task:** Revenue for offline purchases in Google Analytics (detailed by User-ID).

1. Google analytics allows to set the user-id through code:

   `ga('set', 'userId', USER_ID);`

   so session (cid) will be connected to this userid.
2. Google analytics allows to set the revenue through e-commerce code:

`ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {          // Transaction details 
  'id': 'T12345',                         // (Required) Transaction id (string).
  'affiliation': 'Google Store - Online', // Affiliation (string).
  'revenue': '37.39',                     // Revenue (currency).
  'tax': '2.85',                          // Tax (currency).
  'shipping': '5.34',                     // Shipping (currency).
  'coupon': 'SUMMER2013'                  // Transaction coupon (string).
});`

**Question:** Could anyone help, how to connect e-commerce purchase to specific userId? so I mean purchase has been done by this specific client.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ga measurement protocol to tie online to offline conversions

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/